# I always get this error Trying to get property 'nama_lengkap' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-7

index.blade.php

```
                <td class="sorting_1" style="">{{ $no+1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ $d->user->nama_lengkap }}</td>
```

TicketController

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $data = Ticket::with('User','Kategori','Prioritas','Status')->when($request->keyword, function ($query) use ($request) 
        {
            $query->where('judul', 'like', "%{$request->keyword}%");
            })->paginate(5); 
            $data->appends($request->only('keyword'));

            
            return view('admin.crud_ticket.index', compact('data'));         
        }
```

model Ticket

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

model User

```
public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class);
    }
```

if you have a solution to the problem that i am experiencing please help me

Comment: if i take the id, it works
{{ $d->user_id but if I fetch $d->user->nama_lengkap it doesn't work

Comment: no one can answer? oh this is great

Comment: I just found the answer, it turns out my ticket data. what I made with tinker has user_id 16, whereas I only have 3 user data which have id 20, 24, 25 this is very annoying and it makes me laugh :)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer, it turns out my ticket data. what I made with tinker has user_id 16, whereas I only have 3 user data which have id 20, 24, 25 this is very annoying and it makes me laugh :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasOne` instead of `belongsTo` in model `Ticket`

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```